# What means this GoAsync(() => GetPackagesExecute(serviceType)); in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code like this:

```
GoAsync(() => GetPackagesExecute(serviceType));
```

how to understand this code?, what means the braces without name method?

Comment: this means that you're invoking `GetPackagesExecute` method with parameter `serviceType` using a generic delegate.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh - No it doesn't. You are passing an action that will invoke GetPackagesExecute to GoAsync.

Comment: Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx. The empty "()" means you are not passing in any input parameters.

Comment: @erno Seen from here, you could even be building an expression tree, and not a delegate... and I won't express myself to the retun value or absence of it of `GetPackagesExecute` (so `Action` or `Func<something>`)

Comment: `Action`'s aren't delegates? @Erno

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh He isn't invoking `GetPackagesExecute`... He is passing a delegate (or an expression tree) to `GoAsync`... `GoAsync` *perhaps*, *at a certain point* will execute the delegate. The point is *perhaps*.

Comment: @Praval - Exacly. The delegate doen't expect one. What do think `serviceType` is?

Comment: Haha, I'm up voting as this has caused a debate!

Comment: I wrote 'invoke' to make a little sense to OP, if he/she's not aware of these .Obviously 'GetAsync` is the owner of what exactly is going to happen at some point.

Comment: I am sure you guys are 'really' helping the OP understand this. How about not taking it too literally. You are talking too advanced, I am sure that if they don't know what a lambda is, they have never came across actions. Help people learn, not drive them away, that's my philosophy on this site.

Comment: @Keith - that's why I told some invocation.My fellas brought `action` in :)

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Yeah, you comment was fine. I think because you was trying to help by dumbing it down slightly, it just invited people to correct you even though you was trying to help them start off small. It is a interesting community of people this one :)

Comment: This is basically a C# equivalent of the Gagnam style and is call a lambda style in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to tell you exactly what those methods do, because they aren't "standard" methods...

The `GoAsync` for example could have various signatures:

```
void GoAsync(Action action);
void GoAsync(Func<FooType> func);
```

or even more complex, like:

```
void GoAsync(Expression<Action> action);
void GoAsync(Expression<Func<FooType>> func);
```

Let's say that the `GoAsync` has a signature like:

```
void GoAsync(Action action);
```

Now, `GoAsync` accepts as a parameter a delegate, that is a reference to a function. This function mustn't have any parameter and mustn't return anything (if we had chosen the second signature, `void GoAsync(Func<FooType> func);`, then the function would have returned a `FooType` object). `GoAsync` then can execute that function reference and do some operations on it. Note that `GoAsync` could even *not* execute that delegate.

```
() => GetPackagesExecute(serviceType)
```

This creates an anonymous function that doesn't have any parameter and that has as the body `GetPackagesExecute(serviceType)`, so in its body it simply executes the `GetPackagesExecute` with a parameter `serviceType` (that is probably a local variable or a field/property).

In functional language this is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Currying) (creating a function that calls another function, the called function has more arguments than the created function). In this case the anonymous function has 0 arguments, `GetPackagesExecute` has one argument.

Technically this anonymous function could return the return value of `GetPackagesExecute()`, so it is equivalent to both:

```
void AnonymousMethod()
{
    GetPackagesExecute(serviceType);
}
```

and to

```
FooType AnonymousMethod()
{
    return GetPackagesExecute(serviceType);
}
```

The exact "type" of the anonymous function is selected by the C# compiler based on the signature of `GoAsync()`. This is called [type inference in lambdas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx).

Now, the

```
GoAsync(() => GetPackagesExecute(serviceType));
```

together will:

- Create an anonymous function (it is a little more complex than this... there is some C# compiler-magic here, but you can ignore it)
- Create a delegate to that anonymous function (this is implicit, and done by the C# compiler)
- Call `GoAsync` passing this delegate to it
- The `GoAsync` will probably do something with the delegate

Answer (score 0):

It is something called a lambda expression. It is a fairly advanced topic but it is a pretty core piece of functionality. It is really hard to explain it all so I have found this link for you to look through.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

It will explain everything however depending on your level of experience it might not make any sense, it should give you a jumping block to move on and investigate it further.